# How can I break English L2 pronunciation habits?

Tags: pronunciation

I keep making attempts to help L2 English learners break their strange pronunciation habits with tools like phonetic charts, but it seems like they just relapse. One of the big issues I deal with with L2 English learners in Japan is that they finish words with "o". For example, instead of saying, "Can you get me that?" They say, "Can you geto me thato?" They're trying to enunciate.

I have a controversial way of teaching pronunciation that ends with consonants that seems to be effective, but people just relapse into the behavior of enunciating with the added o. One of my regular students often uses count pronouns with non-count words and says, 'It's a style of English speaking. So, it's okay.'

Let's look at a specific example: walk vs. work. If you have people sound out 'werk' and 'wok', they sound spot-on. Unfortunately, after about 5 minutes, they're right back to saying "WAHELK" and "WHORLK", which just sounds terrible.

How can I solidify their pronunciation?

Comment: Have you tried using listening exercises to emphasise the differences - they listen, write down the words, then say them back. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I haven't tried that specifically, Marcin.  Something similar: they show me with their hands which word I am saying.  They're pretty good at identifying which is which, but their speaking isn't reliable.

Comment: I second what Marcin says: pronunciation is arguably more related to *listening* than speaking.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: I think repetition back is key. That, and accepting that ones pronunciation needs correction.

Comment: Try having them record their own voices reading a passage. Make them listen to a native speaker's voice reading the same thing, then have them listen to their own version. Ask them to identify the differences they hear. Hearing your own voice recorded allows you to be more objective about your sound.

Comment: Marcin, Yeah man....  It's extremely difficult to work with a learner who insists they are correct when they are not because they learned something from another teacher, like it's a accent corner case.  I guess if you're from outer space, you can speak however you want and everyone will understand.  A great example is vowel pronunciation.  One learner insisted that `short i` makes the sound `eh` (`short e`).  `Bit` -> `bet`.  The school I was teaching at was very upset that I spent so much time on the subject.  This is part of why I want to refine my skills.  I guess that means letting go.

Comment: What is "L2" in this context?

Comment: @Karl English is the L2.

Comment: ... meaning "second language"? I normally see it written exactly that way; "English as a Second Language" (ESL).

Comment: Karl, L1 is the Native language.  L2 is the language being studied.  I guess L3's would be other languages being studied, though not actively.

Comment: Not trying to be critical, but if your method is "effective", why do people "relapse"? I ask because you said your method is controversial...have you tried the standard way? What is controversial about your way?

Comment: @JeffSahol, I haven't found a standard way that produces realistic results.  Also, standard ways are as ridiculous, if not more ridiculous than my non-standards.  What's is controversial is what is that it classifies concrete concepts as being abstract and relative, like spacing of syllables and words.  It's difficult to teach about where sounds 'die', even to adults.  People become uncomfortable around the concept of death.

Comment: Sorry for the gratuitous youtube link, but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiU8GPlsZqE) might be worth something.  Or it might just drive you bonkers, who knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a similar problem when I was teaching German in Japan.

If the students are old enough you can explain to them that the phonetic pool of English is totally different from the one they have in Japanese, so they need to learn how to pronounce their words from scratch.

I spent about an hour teaching my student how to pronounce a word he never got right before and when it finally worked, he was really happy - also because he was instantly able to pronounce similar words correctly.

Another situation I had was when a student was able to produce the right sound already when combined with other vowels:

ich ("I" in German)
echt ("genuine", "true")

acht ("eight") <--- my student always pronounced the "ch" as "h" here even though he got it right in the other cases.

So I made him say those words in a row "ich, echt, acht" to correct the "acht".

I realize this is pretty close to logpedics and speech therapy, but it does work in practise given a student who is intrinsically motivated to learn a language.

Comment: My learners always seem to take away a feeling of loss when I spend a lot of time on a topic.  Why do you think he smiled?  Is there something about your style of encouraging your students that encourages this response, or have you unlocked some secret to Japanese culture?

Comment: You do realize that the pronunciation of both 'soft' and 'hard' ch sounds varies a fair bit across Germany in practice, yeah? In particular, the soft ch of 'ich' ranges all the way from [] (or at least, a very indistinct [h]) to [k].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: In fairness, the goal of teaching a second language is usually to teach the "standard" form; and in any case students need to be consistent in their accents, not swerving between regions in the same sentence.

Comment: @Karl: I was teaching standard German at that time. My 'ch' vs. 'h' was meant to serve as an example of the method I used successfully. I have used it for other examples where the student was able to create the correct sound in one case but not in the other.

Comment: @Wolfpack: I do think it depends on the student whether you can use a method like this. If the student wants to prepare for a year abroad or is already abroad but has problems with making native speakers understand what he's saying, then he might be motivated enough to go through a process like this.

Comment: Well, Raku, thanks for the help.  I'll give all this stuff a shot on a couple of students and let everyone know what the outcomes are.  Maybe someone will give other tips as time goes on.

Comment: As a native English speaker I have to concentrate to get the Ich sound right - I'm amazed you managed to teach a Japanese speaker to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I have a trick I use when learning another language: I speak my language (English) with a strong accent of the target language. That gets me into the feel, rhythm, where in the mouth I am making sounds, etc. Then I cut straight over to the target language keeping that feel.

I've been told by native speakers of all sorts of languages that I say words exactly like a native - with absolutely no detectable accent. Maybe you could try that.

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea - a perfect illustration of old habits vs. new

Comment: Hey, that sounds worthy of a chance, Bohemian.  Typically, the complaint from Japanese about Native English speakers' pronunciation of Japanese  is that the timing and inflection is off.  The worst situation is when small `よ` or similar small characters are used.  It's supposed to be pronounced with the preceding character together at the same speed as the rest of the characters, but it's often made too long.  I wonder if they will have some creative output in other ways, though....  I'll repost if they do.

Comment: Agreed.  When living in a foreign country, one way I discovered to reduce my accent was to "make fun of theirs".  By speaking in what (to me) felt like an exaggerated parody of the way that they speak English, I was able to start sounding more like them.

Comment: @AricTenEyck That's exactly what I mean! You should hear my Spanish accent - it's basically a parody, but then I speak Spanish with that accent, and voila! It sound trite, but one should speak Spanish with a Spanish accent. Same of course for all languages.